# itertools.product using list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I want to use list comprehension, instead of itertools.product

```
def pr(l):
    return [''.join(i) for i in [(x,y) for x in l for y in l]]

operators = ['/','*','+','-']
pr(operators)

['//', '/*', '/+', '/-', '*/', '**', '*+', '*-', '+/', '+*', '++', '+-', '-/', '-*', '-+', '--']
```

This works, but I want to modify my function such that it returns combinations in pairs of repeat:

```
def pr(l, repeat=1):
   # list comprehension code here



o = ['/','*','+','-']

pr(operators, repeat=4)
pr(operators, repeat=3)

['////', '///*', '///+', '///-', '//*/', '//**', '//*+', '//*-', '//+/', '//+*', '//++', '//+-', '//-/', '//-*', '//-+', '//--', '/*//', '/*/*', '/*/+', '/*/-', '/**/', '/***', '/**+', '/**-', '/*+/', '/*+*', '/*++', '/*+-', '/*-/', '/*-*', '/*-+', '/*--', '/+//', '/+/*', '/+/+', '/+/-', '/+*/', '/+**', '/+*+', '/+*-', '/++/', '/++*', '/+++', '/++-', '/+-/', '/+-*', '/+-+', '/+--', '/-//', '/-/*', '/-/+', '/-/-', '/-*/', '/-**', '/-*+', '/-*-', '/-+/', '/-+*', '/-++', '/-+-', '/--/', '/--*', '/--+', '/---', '*///', '*//*', '*//+', '*//-', '*/*/', '*/**', '*/*+', '*/*-', '*/+/', '*/+*', '*/++', '*/+-', '*/-/', '*/-*', '*/-+', '*/--', '**//', '**/*', '**/+', '**/-', '***/', '****', '***+', '***-', '**+/', '**+*', '**++', '**+-', '**-/', '**-*', '**-+', '**--', '*+//', '*+/*', '*+/+', '*+/-', '*+*/', '*+**', '*+*+', '*+*-', '*++/', '*++*', '*+++', '*++-', '*+-/', '*+-*', '*+-+', '*+--', '*-//', '*-/*', '*-/+', '*-/-', '*-*/', '*-**', '*-*+', '*-*-', '*-+/', '*-+*', '*-++', '*-+-', '*--/', '*--*', '*--+', '*---', '+///', '+//*', '+//+', '+//-', '+/*/', '+/**', '+/*+', '+/*-', '+/+/', '+/+*', '+/++', '+/+-', '+/-/', '+/-*', '+/-+', '+/--', '+*//', '+*/*', '+*/+', '+*/-', '+**/', '+***', '+**+', '+**-', '+*+/', '+*+*', '+*++', '+*+-', '+*-/', '+*-*', '+*-+', '+*--', '++//', '++/*', '++/+', '++/-', '++*/', '++**', '++*+', '++*-', '+++/', '+++*', '++++', '+++-', '++-/', '++-*', '++-+', '++--', '+-//', '+-/*', '+-/+', '+-/-', '+-*/', '+-**', '+-*+', '+-*-', '+-+/', '+-+*', '+-++', '+-+-', '+--/', '+--*', '+--+', '+---', '-///', '-//*', '-//+', '-//-', '-/*/', '-/**', '-/*+', '-/*-', '-/+/', '-/+*', '-/++', '-/+-', '-/-/', '-/-*', '-/-+', '-/--', '-*//', '-*/*', '-*/+', '-*/-', '-**/', '-***', '-**+', '-**-', '-*+/', '-*+*', '-*++', '-*+-', '-*-/', '-*-*', '-*-+', '-*--', '-+//', '-+/*', '-+/+', '-+/-', '-+*/', '-+**', '-+*+', '-+*-', '-++/', '-++*', '-+++', '-++-', '-+-/', '-+-*', '-+-+', '-+--', '--//', '--/*', '--/+', '--/-', '--*/', '--**', '--*+', '--*-', '--+/', '--+*', '--++', '--+-', '---/', '---*', '---+', '----']
['///', '//*', '//+', '//-', '/*/', '/**', '/*+', '/*-', '/+/', '/+*', '/++', '/+-', '/-/', '/-*', '/-+', '/--', '*//', '*/*', '*/+', '*/-', '**/', '***', '**+', '**-', '*+/', '*+*', '*++', '*+-', '*-/', '*-*', '*-+', '*--', '+//', '+/*', '+/+', '+/-', '+*/', '+**', '+*+', '+*-', '++/', '++*', '+++', '++-', '+-/', '+-*', '+-+', '+--', '-//', '-/*', '-/+', '-/-', '-*/', '-**', '-*+', '-*-', '-+/', '-+*', '-++', '-+-', '--/', '--*', '--+', '---']
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you give some clarity on it?
Sample input and Sample output

Comment: Waht's the problem with what you already have?

Comment: `list(product('/*+-', '/*+-'))`

Comment: @Roy2012 It includes opposites and different orders of the same pair if I had to guess.

Comment: Product contains, by definition, different orders of the same pair. So I'm not sure what's the issue here.

Comment: @Roy2012 You are right, I misread to combinations for some reason, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a generic solution for any value of 'repeat'.

```
def pr(l, repeat=1):
    if repeat == 1:
        return [[x] for x in l]
    sub_prod = pr(l, repeat-1)
    return [ [x] + y for x in l for y in sub_prod ]

o = ['/','*','+','-']

pr(o, 3)
```

Result:

```
[['/', '/', '/'],
 ['/', '/', '*'],
 ['/', '/', '+'],
 ['/', '/', '-'],
 ['/', '*', '/'],
 ['/', '*', '*'],
 ['/', '*', '+'],
 ['/', '*', '-'],
 ['/', '+', '/'],
 ['/', '+', '*'],
 ['/', '+', '+'],
 ...
```

If you want to turn each sublist to a string, use:

```
["".join(x) for x in pr(o, 3)]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your command in a function

```
def f(l):
    return [(x, y) for x in l for y in l]
```

or if you want the same generator behavior as `itertools` has:

```
def f(l):
    return ((x, y) for x in l for y in l)
```

or a more verbose generator syntax:

```
def f(l):
    for x in l:
        for y in l:
            yield x, y
```